# Bypass authorization for clientaccesspolicy.xml in self-hosted WCF Data Service

Tags: silverlight, wcf-data-services

I have been running up the walls trying to get this working. I have a self-hosted WCF Data Service with a Silverlight 5 client. I am trying to implement custom authentication for it. I have the clientaccesspolicy.xml being served up and everything is working fine without the authentication. But with authorization turned on, the SL 5 client just cannot send the Authorization header no matter what, using NetworkCredentials, creating header in the SendingRequest event etc. This works fine with a WPF client.

I think I finally found the reason, it is probably because the access to clientaccesspolicy.xml is being authenticated. How can I avoid this authentication? I came across this solution:

```
<location path="clientaccesspolicy.xml">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

But how can I implement this programmatically? Any input highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it worked out. For anyone having similar issues, check this out : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/wcf/thread/475ebb39-f42d-4429-98b1-1286af745746

It has to do with the clientaccesspolicy.xml file. It has to be served through a separate service which allows anonymous access.